# Mimicking Haskell canonicity (one-instance only) of typeclasses in Agda

Tags: haskell, normalization, typeclass, agda

Agda's mixiture of records and the `instance` keyword give us behaviour similar to that of Haskell's typeclasses. Moreover, ignoring the `instance` keyword, we can have more than one instance for the same type --- something we cannot do in Haskell.

I am at a point where I need Haskell's one-instance only requirement, but in Agda. 
Is there an compiler option or some trick/heuristic to enforce this?

Right now the approach I am taking is,

```
record Yo (n : ℕ) : Set where
  field
    sem : (some interesting property involving n)

open Yo {{...}}

postulate UniqueYo: ∀ {n} (p q : Yo n) → p ≡ q
```

However, whenever I actually use `UniqueYo` the lack of computation leaves my goals littered with things like `...| UniqueYo p p` where I'd prefer `...| refl` or a full rewrite into normal form instead.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Could you give an example of how you use `UniqueYo`? Right now you can instead of postulating `UniqueYo` define it as `UniqueYo _ _ = trustMe` where `trustMe` comes from `Relation.Binary.PropositionalEquality.TrustMe` and computes to `refl` whenever its type rewrites to `x ≡ x` for some `x`.

Comment: Using `trustMe` makes things compute and fixes everything for me...I'm just not at all comfortable using it..I honestly feel a bit scared/worried; until I find a better solution, I suppose I'll use it though. It's usage brings me to another problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36874369/separation-of-concerns-when-is-it-best-to-disassociate-semantics-from-syntax.

Anyhow, thank-you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With newer versions of Agda you could use the [`Prop` universe](https://agda.readthedocs.io/en/v2.6.2.2/language/prop.html) to get definitional uniqueness of a type:

```
{-# OPTIONS --prop #-}
module UniquenessUsingProp where
open import Data.Nat.Base
open import Relation.Binary.PropositionalEquality

-- Convert a Set to a Prop. This could be avoided if e.g.
-- we defined > as a Prop (like in the example in the docs
-- linked above)
data Squash {ℓ} (A : Set ℓ) : Prop ℓ where
  squash : A → Squash A

-- record Yo (n : ℕ) : Prop where -- Both variants works
record Yo (n : ℕ) : Set where
  field
    sem : Squash (n + 1 > n * 2)

-- Since `Yo n` is a Prop and not a set, it can't be the
-- direct argument of ≡. This is not a problem since 
-- it's definitionally equal anyways.
UniqueYo : ∀ {n} (P : Yo n → Set) (p q : Yo n) → P p ≡ P q
UniqueYo P p q = refl
```

Another alternative that produces similar results is using [proof irrelevant record fields](https://agda.readthedocs.io/en/latest/language/irrelevance.html):

```
module UniqunessUsingProofIrrelevance where
open import Data.Nat.Base
open import Relation.Binary.PropositionalEquality

record Yo (n : ℕ) : Set where
  field
    .sem : n + 1 > n * 2

open Yo {{...}}

UniqueYo : ∀ {n} (p q : Yo n) → p ≡ q
UniqueYo p q = refl
```

In both cases, actually using the value in Yo can be difficult, since you need to convince Agda that your code does not depend on the concrete value in `sem`, e.g. by only using absurd pattern matches on it or by producing values in `Prop` or respectively, providing it as an argument to irrelevant functions.